# How can I rotate an image in .NET and output it to the client as a PNG?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-processing, rotation

I have an .aspx file that outputs an image using the following methods:

```
 Server.MapPath("somefile.png")
 Response.ContentType = "image/png";
 Response.WriteFile(fileURI);
```

I have a function that rotates the image by 0-360 degrees and returns it as a bitmap.

How can I take this in-memory bitmap and then write it out to the client as a PNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var m = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(m, ImageFormat.Png);
//might want to set correct mime type here.
Response.BinaryWrite(m.ToArray());
Response.End();
```